# Touch sense controller interface

Tags: spi, interface

I am trying to implement a system where I have to use Touch Sense Controller(TSC) with LPC2138 controller, through SPI interface.

As per my consideration,

MOSI line of LPC2138 --> Din of TSC

MISO line of LPC2138 --> Dout of TSC

Is these consideration correct for SPI interface? Thank you.

Comment: you also need SCLK and possibly CS for SPI

Comment: which TSC part are you using?

Comment: @Jasen, I am using TSC2046. My concern is MOSI to Din and MISO to Dout is correct way to interface. Right? I have connected CS,PENIRQ,Busy, Hold also. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the TSC2046 data sheet http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1847520.pdf
and the LPC2138 data sheet http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC2131_32_34_36_38.pdf
it would seem your assumption is correct.

Provided the LPC2138 is the SPI master, that's how to hook it up.

Comment: See here for an example of someone using the same pins: https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/LCD-Modules#itdb02-28